# How export a table data into a csv file using sqlplus in oracle 12.1

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I need a extact the output of one of select which having more than 200 millions records. So what is the way doing such unload. I can access the DB server via sqlplus. I search through the internet and I found below commands. But seems they are not working 12.1

```
SQL> set markup csv on
SP2-0158: unknown SET option "csv"
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
set colsep ,
set pagesize 0
set lines 1000
```

`colsep` is the separator character used to split the columns. For a .csv file, It should be comma.

Comment: what is mean by set lines 1000